# How to check if ContactsContract have photo or not

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm able to get all my contacts and display it in a listview. I get the photo of the contacts too. My problem is that if the contact don't have the photo, my listview don't show nothing (white space). I'm trying to check in some place if ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI has photo or not, but I'm not able to find some way to do it.

In resume, that I want is, if contact have photo display the photo, if not, display an icon.

Any help will be apreciate!

Code:

```
private final static String[] FROM_COLUMNS = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI
    };
    private final static int[] TO_IDS = {
            R.id.contactName,
            R.id.message_subtitle,
            R.id.contact_imageview
    };
    private static final String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI
    };

    private static final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    private String[] mSelectionArgs = {"%%"};

    private ListView mContactsList;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;

    public contacts() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contacts_list);
        mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, null, FROM_COLUMNS, TO_IDS, 0);
        mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, mSelectionArgs,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

change

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.
```

to

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.
```

in your onCreateLoader:

```
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri, PROJECTION, select, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

In your adapter:

```
 @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contact_imageview);
            Bitmap profileImage = getPhoto(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID)));


            if(profileImage !=null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(profileImage);
            }else{
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_contact));
            }
        }

        private Bitmap getPhoto(String id){

            Bitmap photo = null;
            try{
                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(
                        getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI , new Long(id).longValue()));
                if(inputStream != null)
                    photo= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
            return photo;
        }
    }
```